# Jmeter Correlation - Not able to capture correlation parameter through XPath Extractor and Regular Expression

Tags: xpath, jmeter, qregularexpression

Trying to capture simple Title from response body of HTTP request through XPath Extractor and Regular Expression but getting blank response. Tried Regular Expression through https://regexr.com where it is showing correct response but not in JMeter. Can you please help here.

- [Page Response from where want to extract Title] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6NA0.png)
- [Regular Expression] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkFzI.png)
- [X Path Extractor] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLUVY.png)
- [Response/Debug Results] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iptdm.png)

Comment: Please don't post code, error or other data as image. Please [edit] and post as text instead. You can use images as an addition, but make sure you're trying to describe what's on the images. See also: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

1. [Regular Expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - incorrect scope, you need to switch it to `Body`

   [image]
2. [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xpath-extractor-jmeter) - try `//title/text()` as the query
3. Use correct `Apply to` as in case of several sub-results the PostProcessor will be applied to all of them and subsequent sub-result will overwrite the result of the previous one.

Also be aware of [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules), given your current setup PostProcessors are being executed **after each Sampler**, if you want to extract title of a specific page - you need to make the PostProcessor a child of that Sampler

Comment: Dmitri, Thanks for quick help!! Issue has been resolved through JMeter Scoping Rules.